# A formula for power

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, power

My question is this,
$P= dW/dt.$

dW=**F.dr**

That leads to P= **F.v**
But how?!

The book (Schaum's theoretical mechanics) stated that this formula is true. But I think it is true just in case that **F** is constant, otherwise we have to apply the rule of the product of derivatives for dot product!

Can any one help me and illustrate the bug picture for me?
[image][image]

Comment: $F$ is assumed constant during each slice of time ${\rm d}t$.

Comment: But can we apply this formul for variable force fields?

Comment: Sorry I meant formula* not formul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work $W_{\text{by }\vec{\bf F}}$ by some force $\vec {\bf F}$ over a path $C:\vec {\bf r}(t)$ is $$W_{\text{by }\vec{\bf F}}=\int_C \vec {\bf F} \cdot \mathrm d\vec {\bf r}.$$

Recall $\vec {\bf{v}} = \dfrac{\mathrm d \bf\vec {r}}{\mathrm dt}$, then, for some time interval from $t_0$ to $t$, the work is

$$W_{\text{by }\vec{\bf F}}=\int_{t_0}^{t} \vec {\bf F} \cdot \vec {\bf v}\ \mathrm dt'$$

where the $t'$ is used simply for notation (since we can't have the variable of integration as an integral bound).

We know power is the time derivative of work, therefore,

$$P=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{t_0}^{t} \vec {\bf F} \cdot \vec {\bf v}\ \mathrm dt',$$

and, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that $$P=\vec {\bf F} \cdot \vec {\bf v}.$$

Comment: So I understand that this formula apply even when the force is not constant, am I right?, thank you for your help.

Comment: @SohaibAliAlburihy yes. we never had to impose any restrictions on the force